# Is there a way to deal with month in Python the same way with YearMonth in Java?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

As a Java developer if I have to deal with monthes (compare, increment, delta...)  I will use the [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.
Today I'm coding in Python and I'm looking for something looking alike.

I've looked at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html and find nothing that looks like YearMonth

I think I will have to deal with calendar.

I may have missed something.

Goals :

- Provides a way to calculate months delta between 2 months.
- Be able to convert to and from Date/Datetime.
- Compare it to Date or Datetime.
- be a representation for Marshalling/Unmarshalling. (this is the main point)

Examples of months delta I wish I have :

```py
dt1 = datetime(2019,12,31,23,59,59)
dt2 = datetime(2020,1,1,1,1,1)
ym1 = yearmonth(dt1)
ym2 = yearmonth(dt2)
ym_delta = ym2-ym1
```

ym_delta (or ym_delta.months) should be equal to 1.

```py
ym1 = yearmonth(2018,12)
ym2 = yearmonth(2020,1)
ym_delta = ym2-ym1
```

ym_delta (or ym_delta.months) should be equal to 13

I wish there were a months_utils somewhere.
this lib :
https://pythonhosted.org/MonthDelta/
is close to what I search.

Comment: Which features of ``YearMonth`` are you missing in ``datetime``? ``datetime.date`` should be a pretty close match.

Comment: @blobmaster strange as it might be, Python devs don't necessarily know what features java's `YearMonth` class provide (and even less which of those features you actually need) and might not necessarily want to take the time to learn about this class just to answer your question. IOW, you might have better answers by describing the features you need instead of just linking to some class in Java's doc.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks for the remark. I've try to adress it.

Comment: Ok, thx. Well, I'm afraid there's nothing similar in the stdlib indeed.

Comment: But [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) (not part of the stdlib but a de facto quasi-standard lib) has a `relativedelta` object that you could use to implement a similar API.

Comment: Thx, relativedelta doesn't easily count month delta between dates you have to make some more calculation to get the month delta like in my two examples. But I agree that's the tool to use.

Sadly, I guess my question was a message in a bottle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.date` for all the examples you give. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date

See the supported operations in the table under this link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day

Comment: Thx for your answer. I've enhance my question to argue why I'm looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option to get the month is by using time.localtime()
E.g.

```
import time
date=time.localtime()
year=date[0]
month=date[1]
day=date[2]
hour=date[3]
minute=date[4]
seconds=date[5]
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I've enhance my question to argue why I'm looking for something else.